# SBJsonParser in iPhone app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, json

I'm working with JSON library and see this situation:

**Convert JSON string to NSDictionary**

**Scenario 1:**

```
NSString *jsonString = @"{\"Name\":\"Foo\", Points:5}";
NSDictionary *dictionary = (NSDictionary*)[jsonParser objectWithString:jsonString];
NSLog(@"Dictionary: %@",dictionary);
```

I see the result as followed:

Dictionary: {
    Name = "Foo";
    Points = 5;
}

So that's correct.

**Scenario 2:**

```
NSString *jsonString = @"{\"Name\":\"Foo\", Points:0.5}";
NSDictionary *dictionary = (NSDictionary*)[jsonParser objectWithString:jsonString];
NSLog(@"Dictionary: %@",dictionary);
```

I see the result as followed:

Dictionary: {
    Name = "Foo";
    Points = "0.5";
}
**???**

**Scenario 3:**

```
NSString *jsonString = @"{\"Name\":\"Foo\", Points:-1}";
NSDictionary *dictionary = (NSDictionary*)[jsonParser objectWithString:jsonString];
NSLog(@"Dictionary: %@",dictionary);
```

I see the result as followed:

Dictionary: {
    Name = "Foo";
    Points = "-1";
}
**???**

Why does the JSON library convert the negative numbers or number less than 1 into string?
Do you know how to prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not have the "why", but it may not be an issue for you since you can call for the `intValue` or `floatValue` when retrieving.

```
NSLog(@"Points = %.2f", [[dictionary valueForKey:@"Points"] floatValue]);
```

Comment: I second this... It's what I do as well.